# Ext.apply dont work on listeners in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/beQtF/1/

Now if i write listener code directly in the element then it works

By if apply it then it won't work

```
 Ext.apply(cbox, {
       listeners: {
           'select': function (combo, record, index) {
               alert(combo.getValue());
           }
       }
   });
```

The above code don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ext.JS listeners are added in the constructor, therefore you can't configure the component after it was created. You can create `ComboBox` config separately, apply new set of listeners to it, and create a `ComboBox` with extended config, like so:

```
var comboConfig = {
        id: 'searchInput',
        fieldLabel: 'Search:',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        submitEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: 'search...',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        displayField: 'name',
        width: '100%',
        store: {
           fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
           data: [{
               "abbr": "AL",
                   "name": "Alabama"
           }, {
               "abbr": "AK",
                   "name": "Alaska"
           }, {
               "abbr": "AZ",
                   "name": "Arizona"
           }]
        }
};   

Ext.apply(comboConfig, {
   listeners: {
       'select': function (combo, record, index) {
           alert(combo.getValue());
       }
   }
});

var cbox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', comboConfig);
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [cbox],
    frame: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Or, as [CD pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852319/ext-apply-dont-work-on-listeners-in-extjs/19852636#comment29525435_19852636), you can add them with `on` function:

```
cbox.on({
    select: function(combo, record, index) {
        alert(combo.getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: @aga is there any place in the config where i can pass `.on` function. because i already have the combobox , so i cant create it. i have bunch of overrides which i want to apply to elements. is it possible to write `on` function somewhere in the config to take effect

Comment: @user191542 you already have the combobox object named cbox. invoke its `.on` method and pass it the name of event (select) and handler, as I did in the second example.

Comment: but my question is where to write that `cbox.on` function . i want to write that somewhere inside config so that if i use  `ext.apply(cbox, myconfig)` then it works.

Comment: You can't do it. To add event listeners you have two ways: 1) extend the config with the `listeners` property, after that create object - this is my 1st example; 2) use `.on` method on created object - it's the 2nd example. `on` is the method of any `Observable` object, so you can't invoke it "somewhere inside `config`", because the `config` is just plain JavaScript object.

Comment: 3) _.addListener_ as _.on_